# Xamarin Version 4.0.8 Android Version: 4.6.8 LinkAssemblies issue

Tags: android, mono, xamarin

I updated my Xamarin Studio to the latest version today, and now I get errors compiling my apps.

I get the following error:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: Error executing task LinkAssemblies: Failed to resolve Android.Runtime.JavaArray`1<!0> Android.Runtime.JavaArray`1::FromJniHandle(System.IntPtr,Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) (ProjectABC)

Any ideas ?

=== Xamarin Studio ===

Version 4.0.8 (build 2)
Installation UUID: 11c63c7f-e0be-4066-b8f0-39f8a0635818
Runtime:
    Mono 2.10.12 (mono-2-10/c9b270d)
    GTK 2.24.16
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Package version: 210120000

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 4.6.2 (2067.2)
Build 4H1003

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 6.2.7.1 (Enterprise Edition)
Hash: 947e664
Branch: 
Build date: 2013-30-05 18:02:40-0400

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Xamarin.Mac: Not Installed

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 4.6.8 (Enterprise Edition)
Android SDK: /Users/stephen/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-mac_x86
    Supported Android versions:
        2.1 (API level 7)
        2.2 (API level 8)
        2.3 (API level 10)
        3.1 (API level 12)
        4.0 (API level 14)
Java SDK: /usr

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 400080002
Git revision: 0a09117dec1aed78c735ac46f7a50ae7d12f7a7a
Build date: 2013-05-16 19:36:29+0000
Xamarin addins: 78d0437c3f92ae13042f81e5fd9487e2c28d5fbc

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.8.3
Darwin localhost 12.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0
    Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013
    root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Answer (score 0):

This propably was because of the new version of Xamarin Studio not supporting your current installed Java version, please consider deleting this question as i don't think is helpful anymore after 2 years.